# Error while deploying war file to JBoss eap 7.0

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

> {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"DocsUploaderService-0.1.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"DocsUploaderService-0.1.war\".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"DocsUploaderService-0.1.war\"
>       Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0027: Failed to parse XML descriptor \"/C:/Users/user/Downloads/jboss-eap-7.0.0/jboss-eap-7.0/bin/content/DocsUploaderService-0.1.war/WEB-INF/web.xml\" at [2,191]
>       Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix \"xsi\" (for attribute \"schemaLocation\")
>
> at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,191]"}}

Thanks in advance if any help

Comment: Apparantly `DocsUploaderService-0.1.war/WEB-INF/web.xml` is not the proper xml, the namespace prefix `xsi` was not declared. [Edit] your question and add this XML file.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem of an undeclared namespace prefix (xsi:), do any one of the following:

1.Replace xsi: with soapenv: in the SOAP envelope element names.

2.Change xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" to xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/".

3.Use a default namespace by changing xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" to xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" and removing xsi: in the SOAP envelope element names.